# Don't select duplicate emails

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql database with table containing emails and date

```
 Email             Date
 abc@gmail.com     2020-05-05
 abc@gmail.com     2020-05-05
 abc@gmail.com     2020-04-05
 abc@gmail.com     2020-04-05
```

I want to fetch only unique emails on the base of date

```
 Email             Date
 abc@gmail.com     2020-05-05
 abc@gmail.com     2020-04-05
```

I have tried with distinct but it only gives me one record, also tried where not exits etc but didn't work. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email,`Date`
FROM table;
```

[jdoodle.com/a/27E9](http://jdoodle.com/a/27E9)

Comment: Thanks @aviboy I guess I found the issue actually date was stored as 2020-05-27T10:18:28Z so instead of SELECT DISTINCT Email,`Date`
FROM table; I guess I have to use SELECT DISTINCT Email,Date(`Date)`
FROM table;

Comment: Also assume I have Id and want that too

Comment: dont forget to accept answer if this help you. @sukhwinder-sodhi